# How to access Oracle system tables from inside of a PL/SQL function or procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00942

I am trying to access information from an Oracle meta-data table from within a function.  For example (purposefully simplified):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
IS
    users_datafile_path VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT file_name INTO users_datafile_path
        FROM dba_data_files
        WHERE tablespace_name='USERS'
        AND rownum=1;
END MyProcedure;
/
```

When I try to execute this command in an sqlplus process, I get the following errors:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/12     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I know the user has access to the table, because when I execute the following command from the same sqlplus process, it displays the expected information:

```
SELECT file_name
    FROM dba_data_files
    WHERE tablespace_name='USERS'
    AND rownum=1;
```

Which results in:

```
FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/users.dbf
```

Is there something I need to do differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that `SELECT` is not only grantet through a **role**, but that the user actually has the grant. Grants by roles do not apply to packages. See this [post at asktom.oracle.com](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319).

Also, try `sys.dba_data_files` instead of `dba_data_files`.

Comment: It was the privileges thing.  I granted my user select on dba_data_files and the procedure was created without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Specify WITH GRANT OPTION to enable the grantee to grant the object privileges to other users and roles.

```
GRANT SELECT ON dba_data_files TO YOUR_USER WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing the table name with `sys.` as in

```
FROM sys.dba_data_files
```

Answer (score -1):

For selecting data from `dba_data_files`, grant select from SYS user to USER. Example:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dba_data_files TO YOUR_USER;
```

After that recompile your Procedure.